# Infinite convex sum

Tags: analysis, convex-analysis

On page 524 of paper **https://www.jstor.org/stable/2039405?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents** the following result mentioned is:

If $X$ is a convex subset of $\mathbb C$, $(z_n)$ be sequence of elements in $X$ and $(\alpha_n)$ be sequence of positive numbers such that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\alpha_n =1$, then $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\alpha_n z_n$ is in $X$.

How can we prove it? Is it also true in any normed space or atleast finite dimensional normed space?

Comment: Not true in infinite dimesnional normed spaces. Example: $\sum \frac {x^{n}} {2^{n}}$ does not belong to the set $X$ of all polynomials on $[0,1]$.

Comment: OP says that $X \subseteq \Bbb{C}$, so it can't be the set of polynomials.

Comment: As stated, it's not true even in $\ \mathbb{C}\ $, since $\ \sum_n\alpha_n z_n\ $ can be divergent. Take $\ z_n=3^n\ $ and $\ a_n=\frac{1}{2^n}\ $, for instance. Then $\ z_n\ $ all lie on the positive real axis, a convex set, but $\ \sum_\limits{i=1}^n\alpha_i z_i\rightarrow\infty\ $ as $\ n\rightarrow\infty\ $.  Presumably, the paper you cite is implicitly assuming that $\ \sum_n\alpha_n z_n\ $ converges.

Comment: Yes, true for $\mathbb R^n$ and not just $\mathbb C$ with the added assumption $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\alpha_n z_n$ converges.  Let's see if there is a reference, before I try to write it down.

Comment: The paper cited says (for $\ \mathbb{C}\ $) that it was "recently proved by J.P. Williams", whom the author acknowledges at the the end of the paper for "many helpful and informative conversations", but unfortunately gives no indication of where, or even if, the proof of the result has been published. I would take that as an indication that it *hadn't* been published at the time the final version of the paper was submitted.

Comment: More generally: if $\mu$ is a Borel probability measure supported by $X$, and the barycenter $\int_X x\;d\mu(x)$ exists, then the barycenter is in $X$.

Comment: @GEdgar So here  we are considering Borel probability measure which gives value $\alpha_n$ on $z_n$ and on other singleton set to be zero. And then barycenter is nothing but $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\alpha_nz_n$. Can you please give reference for this general fact?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Can we find counterexample in infinite dimensional space if we put extra condition that $\sum_n \alpha_n z_n$ is convergent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Let $X$ be a convex subset of a finite-dimensional affine space $E$.  Let $x_k \in X$, $\alpha_k > 0$, such that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \alpha_k = 1$.
> Assume $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \alpha_k x_k$ converges.  Then $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \alpha_k x_k \in X$.

(If we like, we may subtract $x_1$ from everything to reduce to the case where $0 \in X$, so $E$ is a vector space, not merely an affine space.  But I have not done that.)

The proof is by induction on the affine dimension $n$ of $E$.

First consider the case $n=0$.  Then $X$ is a single point $X = \{x_0\}$.  So $x_k =x_0$ for all $k$ and $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \alpha_k x_0 = x_0 \in X$.

Now, for the induction step, let $n \ge 1$ be the affine dimension of $E$ and assume our result is true for any  dimension ${} < n$.

We have a convex set $X \subseteq E$,  points $x_k \in X$ ($k=1,2,\cdots$), scalars $\alpha_k > 0$ ($k=1,2,\cdots$),
such that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \alpha_k =1$ and
$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \alpha_k x_k$ converges to a point $x_0 \in E$.  We want
to show $x_0 \in X$.  Assume (for purposes of contradiction) that $x_0 \notin X$.
Apply the [Hyperplane Separation Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperplane_separation_theorem) to the disjoint nonempty convex sets $X$ and $\{x_0\}$.  There is a nonconstant linear functional $L$ on $E$ and a scalar $\lambda \in \mathbb R$ such that $L(x) \ge \lambda$ for all $x \in X$, and $L(x_0) \le \lambda$.  I claim that $L(x_k) = \lambda$ for all $k$.  Indeed,
$L(x_k) \ge \lambda$ since $x_k$ in $X$; if $x_k > \lambda$ for some $k$, then
$$
\lambda = L(x_0) = L\left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty\alpha_k x_k\right) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty\alpha_k L(x_k) 
> \sum_{k=1}^\infty \alpha_k \lambda = \lambda,
$$
a contradiction.  [A linear functional on a finite-dimensional space is automatically continuous.] So $L(x_k) = \lambda$ for all $k$. Now consider the affine space $E_\lambda = \{x \in E : L(x) = \lambda\}$ of dimension $n-1$, and the convex set
$X_\lambda = \{x \in X : L(x) = \lambda\}$ contined in $E_\lambda$.  We have $x_k \in X_\lambda$ for all $k$ and $x_0 \in E_\lambda$.  By the induction hypothesis, $x_0 \in X_\lambda$ so $x_0 \in X$.

This completes the induction.